# How to get value checkbox on modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

How to get value from input checkbox to modal bootstrap ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Get Values of Selected Checboxes</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function(){
            var favorite = [];
            $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function(){            
                favorite.push($(this).val());
            });
            alert("My favourite sports are: " + favorite.join(", "));
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sport"> Football</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="sport"> Baseball</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="sport"> Cricket</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="boxing" name="sport"> Boxing</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="racing" name="sport"> Racing</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="sport"> Swimming</label>
        <br>
        <button type="button">Get Values</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to change alert to modal bootstrap ?
[Source Code](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-get-values-of-selected-checboxes)

Comment: please update you question with the relevant code segment(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Modal event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var favorite = [];
    $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function() {
      favorite.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#myModal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $("#checkid").html("My favourite sports are: " + favorite.join(", "));
    });
  });
});
```

Modal HTML

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="checkid"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcut1me0/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add things to the body of a bootstrap modal by using the following:

```
modal.find('.modal-body').text('Your favourite sports are: ' + nameOfVariable);
```

You need to collect the inputs when the modal is called

```
$("#yourModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    var modal = $(this);
    var favorite = [];

    $.each($("input[name='sport']:checked"), function(){            
        favorite.push($(this).val());
    });

    var favorites = $.map(favorite, function(value){
        return (value);
    });

    modal.find('.modal-body').text('My favourite sports are: ' + favorites.join(", "));
});
```

Don't forget to add the change the button information and add the modal (and include Bootstrap CSS and JS libraries).

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/nallenanderson/pen/XdGYJK) that will walk you through the HTML portion, too.

Checkout the official [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) documentation if you still need help.